# Javascript file being generated by Tomcat/Eclipse/Tapestry, slowing website down with large requests and lots of parsing. How to minify/optimize it?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, tomcat, tapestry

The filename is:

```
H4sIAAAAAAAAAIXNQQrCMBCF4XGhXkREhE500QNN41SqlYS86aKeyat5B4mQgJu6$002ffl47$002fWm9ZNotSWiDR2dAGpw8GmIJn4awwTX8plP3LqYggWbo$002fINxMv2p2Z$002fWPba9$002brtK3dFmkSFpbmiErLaF9WN4u$002fdkC6V1ZJd83eteSggV83nHzax7d8QAQAA.js
```

(it's the same name every time).

I have determined that Tomcat/Eclipse/Tapestry generate this js file upon starting the web server. However, I cannot find a way to modify the file at all.

The first few lines of the file are:

```
/* /assets/scriptaculous/5.1.0.5/prototype.js */;
/*  Prototype JavaScript framework, version 1.6.0.3
 *  (c) 2005-2008 Sam Stephenson
 *
 *  Prototype is freely distributable under the terms of an MIT-style license.
 *  For details, see the Prototype web site: http://www.prototypejs.org/
 *
 *--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

However, I also have determined that we do not have this prototype.js file installed anywhere either.

When running Google's PageSpeed, I see that the file is a 239 KB file, of which 140 KB are parsed during initial page load (and can be minified by 23 KB). It takes the majority of the time on page load.

Has anyone else ever encountered this js file before? If so, how did you deal with it?

Comment: A quick help is that you could have Tomcat gzip JavaScript files. You could also enable caching, so the file isn't continually requested

Comment: Thanks. Is there a quick way to add gzip to Tomcat?

Comment: The way I do it is that in conf/server.xml, I edit the `<Connector>` and add these attributes: `compressableMimeType="application/javascript" compression="on" compressionMinSize="20"`. You can obviously add other MIME types for other file types (don't use image MIME types). I hope someone can actually answer your question though, this is just a temporary help

Comment: Thank you very much with your response! I'll test this and let you know if it helps.

Comment: No problem, I hope it does help. It should definitely reduce the size of the file sent to the browser, at least. You can look in your browser's console (at least Chrome/Firefox...IE doesn't show the compressed size, I think) and see the size of the file downloaded...it should be smaller than the actual size. Make sure you clear your browser cache after server changes, so the browser definitely requests a new copy from the server

Comment: You should look into upgrading to a version of Tapestry newer than 5.1; Tapestry is currently on 5.3 with 5.4 in alpha. The problems you are experiencing have been fixed years ago.

Comment: What Tapestry is doing here is building a list of all the JavaScript files needed for the page and then assembling them into a single file to be downloaded. This includes Prototype, Scriptaculous, Tapestry's own JavaScript (to support Zone components, client-side validation, etc.).  Subsequently, we've done a better job of breaking this up into smaller chunks; 5.2 adds Gziping and caching, 5.3 adds minimizations, 5.4 adds async via RequireJS.  Look to upgrade, you're missing out on a lot!

Comment: Thank you for your response, but our system has to stay with Tapestry 4 (yes old, I know). Is there a way to deal with this problem then with Tapestry 4?

Comment: I don't even remember my way around the T4 code anymore. Anything is possible, and you could create your own version of T4 that exposed each JavaScript library separately, rather than try to aggregate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clientside logic (validation / ajax etc) in Tapestry is built on top of prototype.js. In Tapestry 5.4 (not yet released) this will be easy to swap out for jQuery or another 'foundation' framework.

[Javascript Stacks](http://tapestry.apache.org/javascript.html#JavaScript-JavaScriptStacks) were introduced in Tapestry 5.2 where multiple javascript files can be bundled into a single file.

If you look inside the core tapestry jars you will find prototype.js bundled inside. Tapestry is capable of serving js files from the classpath and depending on what version of Tapestry you are running, it has most likely bundled a few core js files together.

Tapestry has some smarts so that js files are not cached in development mode but are aggressively cached in [production mode](http://tapestry.apache.org/configuration.html#Configuration-tapestry.productionmode). It does this by generating unique filenames for your application version and far-future cache expiry response headers.